# Extending configobj on python to handle custom comment marker

Tags: python, configobj

I have a config file, key and value pairs without sections. I'm trying to use [configobj](https://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to parse it, but comments on my config files start with // rather than #

In the configobj documentation I found an example but it doesn't work to me:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj

class ConfigObjCustom(ConfigObj):
    COMMENT_MARKERS = ['//']


config = ConfigObjCustom('hello.conf')
```

Is there a way to extend configobj to support other comment markers?

Comment: I tried also with ';' as comment, it also did not work with the example in configobj.

Answer (score 1):

I also could not get the suggested example with inheriting a new object with changed `COMMENT_MARKERS` to work.

But the steamroller approach to solve the problem would be to read the file, replace the comments and then feed it to configobj. I did a quick test and it worked well enough:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
import re
from io import StringIO

with open('hello.conf') as f:
    file_contents = re.sub('//', '#', f.read())

print(config['SOMEKEY'])
```